# Find out how complete a translation is based on the binary mo file

Tags: gettext

Based on the binary `*.mo` file I would like to find out how complete the language is translated.

When I would have a `*.po` file it would be easy of course. I also tried de-compile the mo-file via `unmsgfmt` but this do not contain empty strings.

Might it be possible to somehow count the empty strings while using `msgfmt` and store that info in an extra variable?

Or is there any other approach?

Comment: FWIW, `file /usr/share/vim/vim*/lang/*/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo` tells me how many message there is in each catalog for each language supported by `vim` for instance.